# Communicating With iPhone With libusb

Tags: iphone, objective-c, libusb

I have a program that essentially wants to be able to have the user plug in their iPhone or iPod Touch, then receive some info based on what device they are using and what firmware version they have. I have read into libusb a little, but I'm unsure on how to communicate and what info I would actually need from the device. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [iRecovery](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/libirecovery). It's an open source tool used to assist in jailbreaking iPods and iPhones. It uses libusb and should help get you started.

Comment: Explored the code a bit, but honestly I'm lost on where to staart. I'm not a very experienced programmer, so that dense C code makes little sense to me. Any chance you could help me out here?

Comment: Sorry, that stuff is a little over my head too.